# GLTF export/import Sketchup 2017 to Blender 2.80 overrides origin and local axis orientation

Tags: export, import, file-format, axis, gltf

I'm exporting a .glb file from Sketchup 2017 using the KhronosGroup GLTF exporter and importing it into Blender 2.80 using the KhronosGroup GLTF importer.

Once the file is imported I get the following **Issues**:

- A root object is added to the scene and all object are now its children.
- Origins for all objects are set to x:0,y:0,z:0 (same coords of the root object) individual object origins are now way outside their geometry.
- Individual axes orientation for all objects are reset.
- Global and local axes of the root are inconsistent (by design?)

To return to the original setup I have to
- Use Set Origin -> To Geometry
- Select individual object, enter edit mode, rotate all faces relative to the local axis
- In object mode, compensate for relative local rotation and rotate the object back to its original orientation in the main scene

I need the local origins and their rotations to remain the same when moving from Sketchup to Blender because the are used in a WebGL game this asset is being used in.

I cannot use other export formats like Collada and FBX as they tend to present other problems (for example losing naming of object groups).

Image references:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The issue may be linked to this issue with the GLTF exporter for Sketchup:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/issues/1662